# Django form in a table can't get right parameters

Tags: django, html

```
<tbody>
          {% for sec in sec_list %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{sec.c_id_id}}.{{sec.sec_id}}</td>
              <td>{{sec.title}}</td>
              <td>{{sec.name}}</td>
              <td>{{sec.time}}</td>
              <td>{{sec.r_no_id}}</td>
              <td>{{sec.cur}}/{{sec.capcity}}</td>
              <td><form method="post" role="form" action="">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="{{sec.c_id_id}}.{{sec.sec_id}}" name="course" id="course">
                  <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="{{sec.cur}}" name="num" id="num">
                  <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="{{sec.capcity}}" name="limit" id="limit">
                  <p class="form-action">
                      <input type="submit" value="选课" class="btn btn-link">
                  </p>
              </form></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I want to use a hidden form to transfer some parameters in a table.My code is above.But when I use
    request.POST.get("limit",'')
,I got a null one.How to fix it

Comment: You can't get null (`None`) with that, you can only get `''`

Comment: I mean '' actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your html code by replacing the **type="submit"** to **type="hidden"**,

```
          <td><form method="post" role="form" action="">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="{{sec.c_id_id}}.{{sec.sec_id}}" name="course" id="course">
              <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="{{sec.cur}}" name="num" id="num">
              <input class="hidden" type="hidden" value="{{sec.capcity}}" name="limit" id="limit">
              <p class="form-action">
                  <input type="submit" value="选课" class="btn btn-link">
              </p>
          </form></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those inputs be `type=hidden` instead of `class=hidden`?

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{sec.capcity}}" name="limit" id="limit">
```

The `type=submit` in all of them makes no sense to me as it is supposed to be used only in submit buttons.